# Finding specific content ID for errors thrown in upgrading 2013 content dB to SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server

Content DB running successfully in SP 2013 but in upgrading same content DB to SP 2016, fatal error is thrown for content supposedly still using “2010 experience”.  How do I find the source of the error so it can be fixed or deleted?  Have tried to upgrade using Powershell’s ‘Mount-SPContentDatabase’ operation.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to upgrade a SharePoint 2013 content database that contains site collections with the SharePoint 2010 experience to SharePoint 2016 the upgrade operation will fail.

And you will get the following error in the upgrade logs: "ERROR Please upgrade sites using SharePoint 2010 experience in database Intranet-Content-1 to SharePoint 2013 before proceeding..."

Then you could use the PowerShell script to upgrade all site to SharePoint 2013 experience.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$webApps = Get-SPWebApplication
foreach($webApp in $webApps)
{
$sites = $webApp.Sites
foreach($site in $sites)
{
Upgrade-SPSite $site.RootWeb.Url -VersionUpgrade -Unthrottled
$site.Dispose()
}
}
```

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

Upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016.

http://nikcharlebois.com/upgrade-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2016/

Comment: Even this is a technically correct advise, you should also note the potential risks behind it. There might be a reason, why some sites still run in SP2010 mode. I have seen lots SP2010 code which was moved to SP2013 without fixing problems. These sites will probably break if blindly doing a VersionUpgrade from SP2010 to SP2013.